# Is there any difference between JS map and PHP associative array?

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6, associative-array

I've been waiting for associative arrays in JS for a long time. Then I've discovered map objects in new standards of JS which reminds me of associative arrays in PHP. Does it have the same purpose as associative arrays in PHP or does it differ at something?

Comment: you cat use them pratically in the same way..

Comment: I'm much more familiar with the PHP side, but just from glancing at some map documentation, it looks like the map object is more flexible than a PHP array with what you can use for keys.

Comment: A JS object is probably the closest to an associative array, and those have existed for the whole lifetime of JS.

Comment: Objects are similar in a "key: value" principle but JS Object doesn't have any associative array functionality on its own. PHP has also objects but there's a reason why associative arrays are separated.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it varies on your expectations. PHP's associative arrays aren't what any other language would call an array, so it depends on if the array part or the key/value part is what you actually want. Most of the time I've seen associative arrays used in PHP, it was essentially as a string -> value dictionary, which a JS object can do fine.

Comment: @loganfsmyth js object can't be iterated over in an increasing order, but js maps and php accosiative arrays can be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes In computer science, an associative array, map, symbol table, or dictionary is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs, such that each possible key appears at most once in the collection

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#maps